# When device is put in landscape mode, a cube in the corner of the screen no longer appears to face forward

Tags: unity, rotation, perspective, aspect-ratio

I've made a cube in the corner of my screen always face forward:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward);
```

If I hold my iPad upright, in portrait mode, the cube looks correct:

[image: Cube seen front-on from its Z face]

But when I rotate my iPad sideways, in landscape mode, the cube no longer appears to face forward:

[image: Cube seen edge-on, X and Z faces equally visible]

Why does this problem occur?

Comment: This looks like the normal result of a distortion caused by the perspective projection you use. Orthographic projections don't have such issues but they may not be appropriate for your situation. Since you're shy on details of what you did and what you want to do, I'm not going to suggest using this.

Comment: You've asked.a couple.of questions now that seem to amount to "How to implement a 3D orientation compass in the corner of the screen" — if that's what you want to achieve, I'd recommend asking that directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The farther an object is from the forward axis of a perspective camera, the more "diagonally" the camera is looking at it, so the more you'll see of its side faces:

[image: Perspective camera diagram]

By default, when you change the aspect ratio of your game window or screen (like by turning a device from portrait to landscape mode), Unity keeps the vertical field of view constant.

That means as the screen gets wider/squatter, you see the same portion of the world top-to-bottom, but you see *more* of the world left-to-right. So the left edge of the new screen view is farther away from the camera's axis in world space than it was when the screen was tall/narrow.

That's why you see so much more of the side of the cube when changing device orientation.

There are a few things you can do to fix this:

1. Use `LookRotation(cubePosition - cameraPosition)` to point diagonally away from the camera.
2. Use an orthographic camera, which always sees objects from the same parallel direction, no matter where they are in the world.
3. Use a separate camera just for this cube widget, which could be orthographic, or could just be positioned so its axis is closer to the cube. That lets you control the perspective of the cube independently from the rest of your scene rendering.